# Referencing `self` in `__old__` in PyContract constraints

Tags: python, self, design-by-contract, contract

I'm working on writing some constraints for a class method using [PyContract](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/contract/1.4) (not [PyContracts](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyContracts/1.4.0)). As a postcondition, I'd like to ensure that the memory address of the instance hasn't changed i.e. `id(self)` should be the same before and after calling the function. How can I do this with PyContract?
I have the following (minimal) code:

```
class Individual:
    def append(self, chrom):
        """
            post:
                __old__.self is self
                len(__old__.self.chromosomes)+1 == len(self.chromosomes)
                self.chromosomes[-1] == chrom
        """
        self.chromosomes.append(chrom)
```

The problem with the constraints here is that in post, I get this error: `_holder instance has no attribute 'self'`

The interesting thing here is that `class Individual` has an `__init__` whose constraints look like this:

```
pre:
    isinstance(chromosomes, list)
post[chromosomes]:
    __old__.chromosomes is chromosomes
    __old__.chromosomes == chromosomes
post:
    hasattr(self, 'chromosomes')
    self.chromosomes == chromosomes
```

As far as I can tell, `PyContract` doesn't like that I call `__old__.self`. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix it:

```
class Individual:
    def append(self, chrom):
        """
            post[self]:
                __old__.self is self
                len(__old__.self.chromosomes)+1 == len(self.chromosomes)
                self.chromosomes[-1] == chrom
        """
        self.chromosomes.append(chrom)
```

[source](http://www.wayforward.net/pycontract/examples/circbuf.py)